# Java - Setting JTable as uneditable using a text Area

Tags: java, swing, model, jtable, jtextarea

I've read that i can use text area wherein i'll put my table to it then set the text area as uneditable which will make the table uneditable.

but when i do it, the text area don't show the table that it contains instead it just show the text area itself.

here's how i do it..

```
    JTable cart;
    DefaultTableModel model;
    JTextArea tArea = new JTextArea();
```

..

```
    model = new DefaultTableModel(data,columnName);
    cart = new JTable(model);
    tArea.add(cart);
    tArea.setEditable(false);
    scroll = new JScrollPane(tArea);
    scroll.setBounds(10,130, 700, 400);
    .
    .
    add(scroll);
```

any idea where I got the wrong part?

Comment: `scroll.setBounds(10,130, 700, 400);`  Use layouts or expect problems.

Comment: Without wanting to state the obvious, but what does a JTextArea (an area to edit text) has to do with disabling the edition of a JTable? If you want your JTable to be non-editable, you should do this through the TableModel: javax.swing.table.TableModel.isCellEditable(int, int). If you are using the DefaultTableModel, then extend it to override the method isCellEditable and make it return the appropriate values.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet That is a very good point, ..now referenced in an answer.

Comment: _add a table **to** a textArea to control the table's editability_ curious: where have you read such nonsense?

Comment: @kleopatra maybe if you do it the other way around (add the textarea to the table and make it as big as the table), drop all borders and make the textarea non-opaque, this could work, but this seems quite insane to accomplish that. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Guillaume Polet already pointed out, I agree that using a JTextArea for setting/changing states in a JTable is inconvenient.

Depending on your requirements I would consider following options:

When you never want the table to be editable you can just override a tables isCellEditable method:

```
JTable table = new JTable( model )
{
  @Override
  public boolean isCellEditable( int row, int column )
  {
    return false;
  }
};
```

or subclassing a JTable for some kind of NonEditableTable. Doing it this way has the advantage, whatever model gets added to this table, your table will never be editable. Exactly this can turn out to be a disadvantage as well, because if your editable state is depended on the data it displays you can't change the state of the table anymore.

In this case it might be preferable (as Guillaume Polet already mentioned) to implement your own kind of TableModel no matter if it is extending a DefaultTableModel or AbstractTableModel and override the method in that class to control the behaviour there.

```
class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel
{
  @Override
  public boolean isCellEditable( int rowIndex, int columnIndex )
  {
    if ( /*FILL IN YOUR REQUIREMENTS TO BE EDITABLE*/ )
     return true;

    return false
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 it's fine to _disable_ the editability (of a model editable cell) in the view but not the other way round.

Comment: Yes, I agree. When its about the general editable state of the table it is a concern of the view. Corrected my answer to differ between the cases. I btw. like the enhancement of JXTable concerning this, since you can change the editable state in general directly in the view ;).